# how do I remove a remote branch when I get an error?

Tags: git, git-branch, gitolite

I have tried the following command and it fails.

```
git push origin :next
remote: error: denying ref deletion for refs/heads/next
To blah.git
 ! [remote rejected] next (deletion prohibited)
error: failed to push some refs to 'blah.git
```

I am using gitolite and cannot find any of this error message in the hooks.  How can I disable this so that I can delete or rename this remote branch?  When I run git branch -r -d origin/next, it appears to go away, but the next git pull brings it right back.

Comment: The "denying ref deletion" portion of the message comes from Git itself. See: builtin/receive-pack.c line 369: rp_error("denying ref deletion for %s", name);

Comment: "git branch -r -d origin/next" only deletes the local-disk 'cache' copy of a remote tracked branch. Only "push" issues commands over the wire in this scenario. Thus, pull will recreate it (the cache). You are effectively asking it to do so. A remote deletion only occurs via "git push REMOTENAME :branchname" or "git push --delete REMOTENAME branchname"

Comment: Thanks Matthew, so how do I remove my remote branch?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure in your gitolite config, you have the rewind flag on so instead of `RW` use `RW+`. That will allow you to delete branches and commits.

`git push -f origin :next`

Comment: Are you using Wildcard repositories? Or just statically defining each repo in the config?

Comment: I bet using wildcards. I recognize this type of problem from work.

Comment: If its wildcards, I believe the "C" CREATOR is only allowed to delete branches unfortunately. I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like the error you get when you try to push to a repo that has `denyDeletes = true`. It's intended to prohibit you from rewriting history in the remote (it is usually accompanied by `denyNonFastForwards = true`). That being the case, you can only delete the branch by deleting it on the remote; `--force` won't work.

Comment: So I am the admin.  How do I turn these off?

Comment: nevermind.  I found the gitconfig line to use and I set it to false, and I still get the same error when I try to remove the remote branch.

Comment: You set it on the remote, correct? If that still doesn't work, there is always the brute force method: Go to the remote and do `git branch -D next`.

Comment: Even with gitolite, a bare repository is still a repository. It responds to the git branch commands (e.g. ssh into the box and cd to the repo's folder). A "git branch -D branchname" should do it. The capital D means force the deletion.

Comment: This worked and it also helped me to understand that I should execute git gc in the bare repo.  so cool!

Comment: git branch -D next didn't worked for me :( 
@user561638 can you please describe how did you resolve it ?