# Why doesn't the remote branch delete?

Tags: smartgit

I am using SmartGit and I can't seem to delete my remote branches. When I try to delete them, it would fail and the error message that I get is along the lines of "Could not delete branch from head". I am not too familiar with git, so am I forgetting to do something before I can delete the branch?

Here is the log from attempting to delete the remote branch.

> 878099 (2014-04-07 21:50:10,148) [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  -
>   shell activated Shell {USERNAME - SmartGit/Hg 5.0.8 (for
>   non-commercial use only)}@AFE99B 878099 (2014-04-07 21:50:10,148)
>   [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  - Activation change from null to
>   Shell {USERNAME - SmartGit/Hg 5.0.8 (for non-commercial use
>   only)}@AFE99B 880880 (2014-04-07 21:50:12,929) [main] INFO
>   q.action  - Performing 'branchDelete, Delete..., Delete the currently
>   selected branch.' menu item from context menu in window
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell@AFE99B:Shell {USERNAME - SmartGit/Hg
>   5.0.8 (for non-commercial use only)} 880882 (2014-04-07 21:50:12,931) [main] INFO              q.dialog  - Showing dialog 7 (@155F302)
>   '@1C53D4E - Delete' (owner: @AFE99B) 880896 (2014-04-07 21:50:12,945)
>   [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  - shell deactivated Shell
>   {USERNAME - SmartGit/Hg 5.0.8 (for non-commercial use only)}@AFE99B
>   880897 (2014-04-07 21:50:12,946) [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  -
>   shell activated Shell {Delete}@155F302 880897 (2014-04-07
>   21:50:12,946) [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  - Activation change
>   from Shell {USERNAME - SmartGit/Hg 5.0.8 (for non-commercial use
>   only)}@AFE99B to Shell {Delete}@155F302 881815 (2014-04-07
>   21:50:13,864) [main] INFO              q.action  - Performing 'Delete
>   Also Remotely' button in window @155F302 owner @AFE99B 881815
>   (2014-04-07 21:50:13,864) [main] INFO              q.dialog  - Showed
>   dialog 7 (@155F302) '@1C53D4E - Delete' (owner: @AFE99B) 881819
>   (2014-04-07 21:50:13,868) [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  - shell
>   activated Shell {USERNAME - SmartGit/Hg 5.0.8 (for non-commercial use
>   only)}@AFE99B 881819 (2014-04-07 21:50:13,868) [main] INFO 
>   q.swt.shellActivation  - Activation change from Shell
>   {*Disposed*}@155F302 to Shell {USERNAME - SmartGit/Hg 5.0.8 (for
>   non-commercial use only)}@AFE99B 881845 (2014-04-07 21:50:13,894)
>   [WorkerThread-1] INFO            sg.command  - Remove branch
>   [CgCommitRef[refs/remotes/origin/BRANCH_NAME]] from
>   smartgit.kX@c3e1af26 for [C:\Users\COMPUTER\USERNAME@1A31360] /.
>   881870 (2014-04-07 21:50:13,919) [WorkerThread-1] INFO 
>   smartgit.core.executable  - Executing the following command:
>   "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" push --porcelain --progress
>   --recurse-submodules=check origin :refs/heads/BRANCH_NAME 881870 (2014-04-07 21:50:13,919) [WorkerThread-1] INFO 
>   smartgit.core.executable  -  in directory: C:\Users\COMPUTER\USERNAME
>   882932 (2014-04-07 21:50:14,981) [QThreadPoolThread-6 (smartgit.aIl)]
>   INFO       smartgit.server  - received command: get-http-credentials
>   882937 (2014-04-07 21:50:14,986) [QThreadPoolThread-6 (smartgit.aIl)]
>   INFO  smartgit.transport.http  - Requesting credentials for
>   6856957067062445309 (userName=USERNAME) 883496 (2014-04-07
>   21:50:15,545) [QThreadPoolThread-3 (smartgit.fe)] INFO 
>   smartgit.command.logging  - stderr: error: failed to push some refs to
>   'GIT_URL_THAT_I_CANT_POST' 883496 (2014-04-07 21:50:15,545)
>   [QThreadPoolThread-0 (smartgit.fe)] INFO  smartgit.command.logging  -
>   stdout: To GIT_URL_THAT_I_CANT_POST 883497 (2014-04-07 21:50:15,546)
>   [QThreadPoolThread-0 (smartgit.fe)] INFO  smartgit.command.logging  -
>   stdout: ! :refs/heads/BRANCH_NAME [remote rejected] (deletion
>   prohibited) 883497 (2014-04-07 21:50:15,546) [QThreadPoolThread-0
>   (smartgit.fe)] INFO  smartgit.command.logging  - stdout: Done 883498
>   (2014-04-07 21:50:15,547) [WorkerThread-1] ERROR           sg.command 
>   - Could not delete BRANCH_NAME from origin. smartgit.ej: Could not delete BRANCH_NAME from origin.    at smartgit.ms.a(SourceFile:47)     at
>   smartgit.atk.a(SourceFile:54)     at smartgit.asl.a(SourceFile:57)    at
>   smartgit.asl.a(SourceFile:20)     at smartgit.iW.a(SourceFile:85)     at
>   smartgit.by.a(SourceFile:42)  at smartgit.jQ.run(SourceFile:115)  at
>   smartgit.Rn.run(SourceFile:53) 883499 (2014-04-07 21:50:15,548) [main]
>   INFO             q.dialogs  - Show (warn): Command Failed - Executing
>   a command has failed. 883501 (2014-04-07 21:50:15,550) [main] INFO
>   q.dialog  - Showing dialog 8 (@838C64) '@76207A - Command Failed'
>   (owner: @AFE99B) 883517 (2014-04-07 21:50:15,566) [main] INFO 
>   q.swt.shellActivation  - shell deactivated Shell {USERNAME -
>   SmartGit/Hg 5.0.8 (for non-commercial use only)}@AFE99B 883517
>   (2014-04-07 21:50:15,566) [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  - shell
>   activated Shell {Command Failed}@838C64 883518 (2014-04-07
>   21:50:15,567) [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  - Activation change
>   from Shell {USERNAME - SmartGit/Hg 5.0.8 (for non-commercial use
>   only)}@AFE99B to Shell {Command Failed}@838C64 884870 (2014-04-07
>   21:50:16,919) [main] INFO              q.action  - Performing 'OK'
>   button in window @838C64 owner @AFE99B 884871 (2014-04-07
>   21:50:16,920) [main] INFO              q.dialog  - Showed dialog 8
>   (@838C64) '@76207A - Command Failed' (owner: @AFE99B) 884874
>   (2014-04-07 21:50:16,923) [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  - shell
>   activated Shell {USERNAME - SmartGit/Hg 5.0.8 (for non-commercial use
>   only)}@AFE99B 884875 (2014-04-07 21:50:16,924) [main] INFO 
>   q.swt.shellActivation  - Activation change from Shell
>   {*Disposed*}@838C64 to Shell {USERNAME - SmartGit/Hg 5.0.8 (for
>   non-commercial use only)}@AFE99B 885305 (2014-04-07 21:50:17,354)
>   [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  - shell deactivated Shell
>   {USERNAME - SmartGit/Hg 5.0.8 (for non-commercial use only)}@AFE99B
>   885307 (2014-04-07 21:50:17,356) [main] INFO  q.swt.shellActivation  -
>   Activation change from Shell {USERNAME - SmartGit/Hg 5.0.8 (for
>   non-commercial use only)}@AFE99B to null

This question is not a duplicate of the one that a few people claimed as duplicate because I want to know how to do it through SmartGit, not through Git Bash. SmartGit does not provide cmd, or at least I am not aware that it is. People with so many reputation allowed the reputation get to their head and stopped reading all together; what a shame.

Comment: Can you check what error you get if you use the normal command-line way of deleting a remote branch? That is, `git push origin :branch-name` (assuming the name of the remote you want to delete the branch from is `origin`).

Comment: @Dolda2000 How do I use cmd via Smartgit? It seems to be GUI based.

Comment: @AndyLester: It doesn't sound like he's having trouble finding *how* to remove the branch, but rather why he can't in this case.

Comment: @AndyLester It is similar, but not the same.

Comment: @dalawh: Sorry, I have no clue. I've never seen smartgit before. I was just thinking that normal Git, if you have access to it, would give a more detailed error message, which would actually explain what's wrong.

Comment: What's SmartGit? It's not a duplicate, oops I misflagged sorry...

Comment: @Dolda2000 I'll see if I can figure it how to access it via cmd.

Comment: @AnubianNoob Thanks... can you report it so someone can remove it as a duplicate...

Comment: @dalawh wat? I don't understand what you said. Whoever reviews will probably see these comments and decide on the duplicity of this post... You should post something saying that it is or isn't a duplicate.

Comment: @AnubianNoob It seems whoever reviewed this has already declared it as a duplicate, which doesn't really help because less people will reply.

Comment: Can't believe I had to flag my own question for a mod to look at it...

Comment: Please post all relevant output of `log.txt` (from SmartGit's settings directory, see About dialog) after having tried to delete the branch.

Comment: @mstrap I added the log to the original post. Hopefully, you can decipher it better than I can.

I just read through it again and it seems that deletion is prohibited, so does that mean that the gitweb host is preventing it?

Answer (score 1):

The `log.txt`contains:

```
! :refs/heads/BRANCH_NAME [remote rejected] (deletion prohibited)
```

which has been received by Git (from the server). This problem could be related to:

[how do I remove a remote branch when I get an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5723511)

You should see the same problem from command line:

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" push --porcelain --progress --recurse-submodules=check origin :refs/heads/BRANCH_NAME
```